# Angular6 Material table multiple filter not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table

I am developing an Angular6 application with angular material. Now facing a problem with filter data from mat-table result using multiple values.

I didn't get any value in the table after filter from form group.

Is this correct way what I am working? If not please help me out the issue.

Please refer the screenshot and find the link [stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-multiple-filter) for the actual view,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have never really used this and I don't know if the following implementation is correct. It can be improved by a big margin I believe.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-multiple-filter-ttewos)

Basically, from what I understand,m by default the behavior when you put a filter is to check if this value exist in the data.

But in your case, you want to check over various column, and do a "multiple" filter.

you need to provide you own filterPredicate function, and handle your filter in there

Comment: You almost there, But there is a small issue the name and email fields if we type "name" or "email" result is not showing.  It will show the character includes the result. ex: If we type "nam" all the data will be shown in the name field includes the charactor